# Codeship, Sinatra, ActiveRecord - configuration

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, codeship

I have a sinatra app working on my computer and am trying to get the tests to run on Codeship. I've reduced it to a tiny subset to see if I can sort out the problem I am having. I would greatly appreciate another pair of eyes...

Here are the key files:

Rakefile:

```
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require_relative "demo_app"

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = "test/*_test.rb"
end
```

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

demo_app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra/activerecord'

require './models/event'
require './models/person'
require './models/registration'

require 'pry-byebug'
```

migrations:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.date :date
    end
  end
end
```

test_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = "test"
ENV["SINATRA_ENV"] = "test"

require_relative '../demo_app'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'rack/test'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
```

event_test.rb:

```
require_relative './test_helper.rb'

describe Event do
  it "can add events" do
    Event.create(name: "An Event")
    Event.create(name: "Another Event")
    Event.all.size.must_equal 2
  end
end
```

So, with that context I setup Codeship. Here are the key settings there:

Setup commands:

```
rvm use 2.2.2
bundle install 
RACK_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Test Pipeline (1 of 1)

```
rake test
```

And now when I push to git, and codeship picks it up I get this error on line 1 of demo_app.rb which is a require to `sinatra/activerecord`:

`rake aborted!
Database URL cannot be empty
.....`

It seems that for some reason, it is not paying attention to the fact that I am running in test mode and so it should use the test clause of database.yml.

Thoughts?

Comment: Your last setup command first executes the default rake task, then sets the environment and runs the migrations. In order to have the correct environment set, I guess you need to specify the env var at the _beginning_ of the command: `RACK_ENV=test bundle exec rake ...`.

Comment: So like this?

RACK_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate

Still get the same error.